# How to use AccessibleObjectFromWindow WinAPI function in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, interface

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317976(VS.85).aspx

```
STDAPI AccessibleObjectFromEvent(
  __in   HWND hwnd,
  __in   DWORD dwObjectID,
  __in   DWORD dwChildID,
  __out  IAccessible **ppacc,
  __out  VARIANT *pvarChild
);
```

What is IAccessible** equivalent in Delphi (2009)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function AccessibleObjectFromEvent(H : HWND; dwID, dwChildID : DWORD; out Acc : IAccessible; var varChild : Variant) : HRESULT; stdcall;
```